# Yii2 Hide Actions in Action Column of a Single Row only

Tags: php, gridview, action, yii2

I have a `GridView` and some of the items in the list are **not** created by the user, but they are pre-defined buy us, the developers.

[image]

In the image above, the row with the ***(not set)*** Store ID is the pre-defined item we created. Since it is pre-defined, it should not have the Action Icons "view", "update", and "delete".

How do we, at least, hide these action icons on our pre-defined items in the `GridView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create new column and set callable `$content` property. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$content-detail

So, for example. Put this code in `Grid` columns:

```
[        
    'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        if ($model->storeId == null) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['view', 'id' => $model->id])
            . Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['update', 'id' => $model->id])
            . Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], ['data-method'=> 'post']);
        }
    }
]
```

This is work in my project like that https://yadi.sk/i/2fWnWZBNffQJL and https://yadi.sk/i/GyHWD9m9ffQK2

Comment: @vitalik_74. exactly where to place above snippet?